# Java HttpClient - allowing restricted headers does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers, httpclient

I am trying to set Connection and Host header in my request builder, but when I want to send this request, I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: restricted header name: "Host"` exception.

I tried to set `jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host` in application.properties, pass
`-Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host` argument to JVM and create net.properties file with `jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=host` property, but nothing worked for me.

Edit:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: restricted header name: "Connection"
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.newIAE(Utils.java:244) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestBuilderImpl.checkNameAndValue(HttpRequestBuilderImpl.java:110) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestBuilderImpl.setHeader(HttpRequestBuilderImpl.java:119) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpRequestBuilderImpl.setHeader(HttpRequestBuilderImpl.java:43) ~[java.net.http:na]
    at com.tenpetr.publictransport.builder.RequestBuilder.buildPostRequest(RequestBuilder.java:33) ~[main/:na]
    at com.tenpetr.publictransport.service.implementation.HttpServiceImpl.sendPostRequestWithBody(HttpServiceImpl.java:38) ~[main/:na]
    at com.tenpetr.publictransport.service.implementation.CacheServiceImpl.getMpvCachedTransportsLocations(CacheServiceImpl.java:75) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(CacheInterceptor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.lambda$execute$1(CacheAspectSupport.java:382) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCache$LoadFunction.apply(CaffeineCache.java:175) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2346) ~[caffeine-2.8.8.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1908) ~[na:na]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2344) ~[caffeine-2.8.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2327) ~[caffeine-2.8.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:108) ~[caffeine-2.8.8.jar:na]
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalManualCache.get(LocalManualCache.java:62) ~[caffeine-2.8.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCache.get(CaffeineCache.java:100) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:382) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:346) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.getMpvCachedTransportsLocations(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.tenpetr.publictransport.service.implementation.TransportLocationServiceImpl.fetchMpvTransportsLocations(TransportLocationServiceImpl.java:87) ~[main/:na]
    at com.tenpetr.publictransport.service.implementation.TransportLocationServiceImpl.getMpvTransportsLocations(TransportLocationServiceImpl.java:76) ~[main/:na]
    at com.tenpetr.publictransport.controller.TransportLocationController.getMpvTransportsLocations(TransportLocationController.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

**JDK version - 11.0.7**

Do you have any suggestion, how to set these headers?

Thanks

Comment: show the stack-trace.

Comment: that is why it is _very_ important you say what version you use, what env, etc. There is an exact duplicate already, and if you would have included everything into the question from the beginning, the answer would have been provided much faster.

Comment: The same thing happens to me as well. I'm using opnejdk-17.0.1. Setting system property "jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders" doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You can set these parameters using System property before you call HttpClient.

```
    static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders", "Referer");
        System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.redirects.retrylimit", "3");
        System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.disableRetryConnect", "true");
        System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.enableAllMethodRetry", "true");
        System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders", "Content-Length");
        System.setProperty("jdk.internal.httpclient.disableHostnameVerification", "true");
        System.setProperty("org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH", "true");
        System.setProperty("tomcat.util.http.parser.HttpParser.requestTargetAllow", "|{}");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Does not worked for me. :/

Comment: @PetrJelínek what is your definition of "does not work". that should absolutely work. I do not know why this answer shows _that_ many flags, when only one `System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders", "Host");` is enough.

Comment: @Eugene When I say it does not work it means in this context that I still have same issue that I wrote in the first post, I think it is clear. But for you - I still got exception with the restricted headers, even when I set this property.

Comment: @PetrJelínek can you include the jdk version and stack trace please?

Comment: @Eugene Original post updated. And yes, I was trying Connection header this time

Comment: According to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213189 the property was added to JDK 12

Comment: Doesn't work here, neither. Using Java 17. :-(  
It works when specified on the command line when starting the JVM but not from the program's main as shown above.